# How to conciliate Devise reset-password route with ApiConstraints?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, http-headers, api-design

I'm using [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) and everything works well until I add API constraints to the routes: `constraints: ApiConstraint.new(version: 4, default: true)`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    scope module: :v4, constraints: ApiConstraint.new(version: 4, default: true) do
      # Token auth routes available at /api/auth
      mount_devise_token_auth_for "User", at: "auth"
    end
  end
end
```

Adding these constraints restrain access to the routes unless the request contains the correct headers:

```
class ApiConstraint
  attr_reader :version

  VENDOR_MIME = "application/vnd.myproject-v%d"

  def initialize(version: "4", default: false)
    @version, @default = version, default
  end

  def matches?(request)
    byebug # <-- I wish there was something like request.current_path available
    return @default unless request.headers.key?("accept")
    request
      .headers
      .fetch("accept")
      .include?(VENDOR_MIME % version)
  end
end
```

I realised this is problematic for the **reset password link** which we get by email:

```
https://myproject.herokuapp.com/api/auth/password/edit?reset_password_token=...
```

... as it can't carry any headers!

I could redirect the user to a webpage which then does an AJAX call with the appropriate headers, but I was wondering if there was a way to enhance my `routes.rb` or `ApiConstraint` class to make an exception on the `/auth/password/edit` route?

Comment: is `request.url` or `request.fullpath` what you are looking for?

Comment: @Shiyason it is! Feel free to make that an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `request.url`, `request.fullpath`, `request.params` to access the data you need.

More importantly, in order to figure out what methods are available to you at runtime, once the REPL opens up on the line where you put your `byebug` debugger entry, you can use these following methods (assuming your using `pry`):

```
ls # display everything in the current scope
cd request # or any other variable or instance variable.
cd .. # you can navigate your code as if it was a filesystem

request.methods.grep /path/
request.methods.grep /url/
request.methods.grep /param/

# or

cd request
methods.grep /query/
```

---

*OP update*

```
# api_constraint.rb
def initialize(version: "4", default: false, exceptions: [])
  @version, @default, @exceptions = version, default, exceptions
end

def matches?(request)
  return true if @exceptions.include? request.path
  ...
end
```

```
#routes.rb
scope module: :v4, constraints: ApiConstraint.new(version: 4, default: true, exceptions: [
  "/api/auth/password/edit"
]) do
  ...
end
```